# How do I size a font in CSS/JS to have a certain margin on the sides relative to its container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I can make a font relative sized to the viewport (if I just put it in the body), with `200vh`, etc. But how do I make it sized to perfectly fit within the container? That is, I want a certain margin such as 8% of the width to be on each side of the text, and for the text to fill the remaining 84%. How can I do this with HTML/JS/CSS?

```css
body {
  font-size: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not pixel perfect, but it will have an approximate result.
By wrapping the text, such as in a `<span>`, you can get the initial text width and font size, which will be used to calculate the final font size using also the width of the container.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', calcFontSize);

var textEl = document.querySelector('span'),
textElParent = textEl.parentNode,
textFontSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(textEl, null).getPropertyValue('font-size')),
textWidth = textEl.clientWidth,
spaceToFill;

function calcFontSize() {
  spaceToFill = textElParent.clientWidth;
  textEl.style.fontSize = (spaceToFill * textFontSize)/textWidth + "px";
}

calcFontSize();
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #fff;
}
body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 8%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span>hello</span>
</body>
```